# How can I understand the download is completed?

Tags: php, download, attachment, file-get-contents

I wrote a simple download system with php, I should store size of downloaded files to database which we can calculate the bandwidth usage of an user later, my code is :

```
<?php

$filename = _FILES_PATHS."/".$_GET['file'];
$type = getFileData($filename); // I wrote this function to return file type
$size = filesize($filename);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO download_logs (user_id,filename,filesize) VALUES (".$_SESSION['user_id'].", '".$_GET['file']."', '".$size."'");
header("Content-Type: ".$type);
header("Content-Length: ".$size);
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=".$_GET['file']);
echo file_get_contents($filename);

?>
```

This code work without problem, but maybe user cancel the download operation before completion, but I store the file size in database.

How can I store downloaded bytes in database or if this is impossible, how can I store file size after download completed ?

Comment: Not really your question, but you suffer both from SQL and file injection attack possibilites.

Comment: There's no way to tell. PHP is just handing over the file data to the webserver, then exiting. That data will sit in the server's output buffers while it's streamed to the user. Once PHP has finished sending data to the buffer (e.g. the `echo` completes), it exits, and the download may still be progressing.

Comment: @MarcB Is it possible to write a `loop` and read byte to byte of file and then store in database then `echo` on page ?

Comment: @BartFriederichs Thanks for your comment, yes I know, I will clear all `$_GET` and `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE` before I use in my program, this is part of my program.

Comment: Sure, but byte-by-byte would be INCREDIBLY inefficient. Working on a per-kilobyte or bigger units would be better. At least then you could use ignore_user_abort() and [connection_aborted()](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#locationmatch) to detect the download being killed.

Comment: @MajAfy: clearing them isn't enough. you're  **DIRECTLY** using $_GET in your file operations, allowing a malicious user to download ANY file on your server they know the path for, e.g. `http://example.com/download.php?file=../../../../../../etc/passwd`

Comment: I think the only way would be to disable output buffering completely, and then manually implement Chunked Transfer-encoding. You could then use connection_aborted to catch downloads aborted before all chunks are transfered. But it can be non-trivial to implement chunked encoding yourself - better to leave it to the webserver.